# I have prepared ferrous sulfate solution in water. After some time, brown precipitates observed. How to prevent the same?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

When ferrous sulfate solution is prepared in water, after some time, brown precipitates appear, how to prevent the precipitates.

Comment: Probably ferrous carbonate. Acidify the solution to avoid that problem.

Comment: Or ferric oxide/hydroxide from traces of $\ce{Fe^{III}}$ in the $\ce{FeSO4}$, or due oxidation. Another option, depending on the purpose, is to use the Mohr salt $\ce{(NH4)2Fe(SO4)2}$, that is less vulnerable to oxidation.

Comment: @Poutnik - Yes think you nailed it. $$\ce{FeCO3 + H2O <=> Fe(OH)2 + CO2}$$ $$\ce{4Fe(OH)2 + O2 <=> 2Fe2O3\cdot3H20 + H2O}$$